# Deleting Records from a DataFrame in Python Using Another DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now - I've read a lot of similar posts and used the code answers from them. Basically I am trying to filter-out (delete) rows from this dataframe:

```
Name: df

       OrderQty InvoiceDate 
CID                        
1000363         6   1/20/2020
1002047         1  10/14/2019
1003565         7   10/9/2019
1003680         5   10/2/2019
1010933         1  12/10/2019

[115547 rows x 2 columns]
Type : 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
Index: CID
```

Using another DataFrame which looks very similar:

```
Name: df2

       OrderQty InvoiceDate 
CID                        
1000363         6   1/20/2020
1002047         1  10/14/2019
1003565         7   10/9/2019
1003680         5   10/2/2019
1010933         1  12/10/2019

[6387 rows x 2 columns]
Type : 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
Index: CID
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between df2 on the column 'CID' (One row per CID - these are the CID's I want to delete from df) and df (Many rows with multiple rows having the same CID)

So far I've tried the following to try and delete rows in df that have a CID with the same a CID:

```
new_df = df[df['CID']].isin(df2[df2['CID']])
```

Gives a KeyError

```
cond = df['CID'].isin(df2['CID'])
new_df = df.drop(df[cond].index, inplace = True)
```

Gives a KeyError

```
new_df = df['CID'].isin(df2).dropna()
```

Gives a KeyError

```
new_df = df[~df['CID'].isin(df2)].dropna()
```

Gives a KeyError

```
new_df = df.query('CID not in @df2')
```

No Error but doesn't remove and records from df

```
new_df = df[~df.CID.isin(df2)]
```

Gives an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'CID'

I'm pretty stuck at the moment - I have shutdown/reset my python app several times, used different code snippets (above) from various posts I've read each time and no change. I think the issue I'm having could be having 'CID' as an Index or the One-to-Many Relationship I'm dealing with?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try running:
```cond = df['CID'].isin(df2['CID'].values)```
```new_df = df.drop(df[cond].index, inplace = True)```
It's similar to one of the first ones you ran, but checking against an array rather than a Series may work.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) works on labels and by default these labels will be the DataFrame's index. In your case CID is the index so this should be as simple as

```
df_new = df.drop(df2.index)
```

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the responses I got df_new = df.drop(df2.index) to work - amazing how such a small line of code makes such a difference! Many thanks for the help!